# I want to navigate sub menus with tab key

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation, submenu

I have a menu and there are sub-menus in this menu.
I can open and hide the sub menu with the click function and CSS.
But I cannot open sub menus with the tab key.
I want to be able to navigate the menu sequentially with the tab key.
When I focus on the upper menu, the sub menu should be active and I should be able to navigate in it with the tab key.
The sub menu should be hidden when focusing on another menu with Tab or Shift + Tab.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pu650xtn/3/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub-menu">
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Photo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Draw</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub-menu">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Who i am</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
    ul{
        list-style: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 1.75em;
    }
    a{
        color: #blue
        display: inline-block;
    }
    a:focus{
        outline: 1px dotted red !important;
    }
    a:visited{
        color: blue;
    }
    .has-sub-menu ul.sub-menu{
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .open-sub-menu.has-sub-menu ul.sub-menu{
        max-height: 200px;
        overflow: visible;
    }
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.has-sub-menu > a').on("click", function() {
        if ( $(this).parent().hasClass("open-sub-menu") ) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("open-sub-menu");
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().addClass("open-sub-menu");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: From UX perspective, I'd advise against doing that. Users don't expect the elements on page to appear and disappear on focus event.

Comment: I agree with @MartinHeralecký. It's perfectly accessible as is. If you change the native browser rules, non-sighted users will get confused.

Comment: My English is not so good, I'm sorry. I guess I couldn't explain exactly what I wanted.
I'm preparing a WordPress theme. They examined my theme and found it problematic to navigate in the menu with the tab key. When navigating with Tab, if the item with focus has a sub-menu, I want that sub-menu to open. (Like I did with jQuery's click function.) Is this a problem for UX.